# string comparison - undefined value

Tags: python

have some little program that asks for input as char - y,b,s and then checks what was the input by comparing it.
the prob' i'm getting when I running the program is-

> NameError: name 'b' is not defined

if the input is, let say, b.
this is my code:

```
print("Please think of a number between 1 and 7")
print("Is it 4? (y,s,b)")
answer=char(input())

if (answer=='y'):
    print("It is Four!")

elif (answer=='s'):
    print("Is it 2? (y,s,b)")
    answer=input()
    if (answer=='y'):
        print("It is two!")
    elif (answer=='s'):
        print("It is one!")
    elif (answer=='b'):
        print("It is Three!")
elif (answer=='b'):
    print("Is it 6? (y,s,b)")
    answer=input()
    if (answer=='y'):
        print("It is Six!")
    elif (answer=='s'):
        print("It is Five!")
    elif (answer=='b'):
        print("It is Seven!")
```

Comment: yes, smaller and bigger?

Comment: @user2160077: Please get rid of the parentheses when using `if` and `elif`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you appear to be using Python 2, you need to use [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) rather than [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input). The difference is that the latter tries to evaluate the expression that you've entered. For example, if you enter `b`, it goes looking for a variable named `b`.

In Python 3, there is no `raw_input()`, and `input()` no longer evaluates the expression. In other words, Python3's `input()` behaves like Python2's `raw_input()`.